# Cant Find RAID 1 md0 drive using mdadm Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid

I used mdadm to create a RAID 1 array using two 3TB drives. After the process, which took all night, I found that the two 3TB drives, /sdb and /sdc, have disappeared from the file explorer. Rebooted the system and they reappeared,then disappeared again after another reboot,they seem to be corrupted with error found in GParted where they can be found:

```
Corrupt extent header while reading journal super block</i>

<i>Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this, some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41
```

I called the new RAID array md0, which now has a folder in /mnt/md0, which is empty.

There is a conf file in /etc/mdadm which reads:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This configuration was auto-generated on Mon, 24 Dec 2018 02:28:48 -0500 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=dna-computer:0 UUID=df25e6e6:cccb8138:aa9f4538:31608c33
```

Not sure if this helps but the command `cat /proc/mdstat` reads:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
unused devices: <none>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is whats mdadm does: it replaces your disks with a RAID identity, which is represented as /dev/md (*md* stands for *multiple device*). From that point, you don’t want direct access to your individual harddisks, because that would compromise the disk array.

As stated in the manual page of [mdadm](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm):

> RAID devices are *virtual* devices created from two or more *real* block
>   devices. This allows multiple devices (typically disk drives or
>   partitions thereof) to be combined into a single device to hold (for
>   example) a single filesystem.

Also see for example [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial.

Comment: my md folder is located at /mnt/md0, does this serve the same purpose? So can I assume that this folder will hold 3TB of storage? also since this is in RAID 1, how would i be able to access the hard drives separately in the case of data loss.

Comment: Your md **device** is at `/dev/md<#>`, which can be **mounted** in the `/mnt/` directory. Type `mount` to see which devices are mounted where. The underlying disks are **not** meant for direct access. If you do this, you risk damaging your md array. Look at mdadm as a layer between your disks and the RAID’ed disks. If one disk gets damaged, mdadm must handle this (by setting the disk to failed and/or remove the disk from the array). So the answer to the question how to access a “degraded” RAID array is: still through `mdadm`.

Comment: I do not have a directory at /dev/md<#>. Just to make sure i understand, if i place files in the mnt/md0 directory, this will essentially be like placing files on the 3TB RAID 1 array and will not take up space on the main drive?

Comment: Check the output of `mount | grep md`; this should show you what device (`/dev`) is mounted (`/mnt`) on `/mnt/md0`. If it shows nothing, this directory is just a directory on your root mount (`/`). If it shows a device, that’s where the data is read from & written to.